# Iterate through my sql result and display in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to get the result from "headline" and "content" to show up one at a time and then fade in and out to the next result in a loop. Currently, it shows all the results at once and the fades in and out and then show all the results again. Any idea on how to get them to show one at a time TIA

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #table1{/*table aspects and design */
            border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            background:#FFFFFF;
            display:none;
            width: 60%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        th{/*align table headers*/
            text-align:center;
        }
        td,th{
            border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<table id="table1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%">
    <? if ($query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Announcements_Current`"))
    {
/* select all information from the table and take it into the page  */
    $query->execute(); 
    while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $head = $result['headline'];/*puts result of headline from table into variable*/
        $content = $result['content'];
        /*puts result of content from  table into variable*/
        echo /* echo the table to display announcements*/'
        <tr>
            <th>
                <h1>
                    '.$head.'
                </h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font size="4">
                    '.$content.'
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>';

     }
}
?>
</table> <!--end of table-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* define script for jquery*/
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {/* for loop to fade in and out the announcements*/

$(document).ready(function() {/*function to fade table in and out*/
$('#table1').fadeIn(2000);
$('#table1').delay(5000);
$('#table1').fadeOut(2000);
}  
)};
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the PHP part works fine?

Comment: Yes, it is just that when I'm looping I'm showing all the results at once instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way.

This won't be a complete solution. I'll try to hopefully make you understand the logic behind doing this yourself.

Loop through the results but instead of echoing them immediately, save them in arrays:

```
<?php
$head[] = $result['headline'];
$content[] = $result['content'];
?>
```

After the loop, only echo the first results. Add some IDs to your `<h1>` and `<td>` while you're at it. You'll need them later.

Then pass the arrays to JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var head = '<?= json_encode($head); ?>';
    var content = '<?= json_encode($content); ?>';
</script>
```

Now that you have the arrays in JS, you have to iterate through them and for each value, change the content of your `<h1>` and `<td>`:

```
for (var i = 0, len = head.length; i < len; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("H1_element_ID").innerHTML = head[i];
    document.getElementById("TD_element_ID").innerHTML = content[i];
}
```

You can probably throw your `fadeIn()`, `delay()` and `fadeOut()` in this loop, to achieve your desired result!

Finally, delete your for and put this one inside `$(document).ready()`.